# ApacheSolr: filter by multiple numeric values

Tags: solr

It's probably VERY simple question but still can't find a solution
Say I have field **id** and want to get all records with id 1,2,3,4,5

Which query should I write?

I've tried something like

```
/select?q=id:1,2,3,4,5
```

and it does not work

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Filter Query over normal Query wherever possible.

[FilterQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) is able to take advantage of the [FilterCache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache), which would be a huge performance boost in comparison to your queries.

```
fq=id:(1 OR 2 OR 3)
```

Comment: So the query become /select?q=*:*&fq=id:(1 OR 2)&wt=json&start=0&rows=50 ? It returns nothing

Comment: Now I see the response but "docs" array is empty. I've checked index again (/select?q=*:*&wt=json) and can confirm that there're records with id 1 and 2 UPD: SORRY, fq=id:1 is working!

Comment: This is "string single" dynamic field which has the following definition in the schema.xml "<dynamicField name="ss_*"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>" Actually name is "ss_entity_id", but I use "id" in the query sample

Comment: I also tried non-dynamic field, that stores pure integer id, in schema.xml: "<field name="entity_id"  type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />" with the same result

Comment: It seems OR operator doesn't work, but I have it enabled in the schema.xml "<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>"

Answer (score 1):

If your `id` field is `int` then this will not work.

`csv` is treated as a `String`. You will have to use the `OR` operator like so `q=id:1 OR id:2 OR id:3 OR id:4 OR id:5` even the query `q=id:1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5` would be matched but treated as `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Try
    /select?q=id:(1 2 3 4 5)

or `/select?q=id:("1" "2" "3" "4" "5")`  in the case your ids need escaping

and check what is your default operator(OR|AND) 
regards